# How do electrons behave in the secondary circuit of a transformer?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons

When the transformer steps up the voltage in the secondary coil, the current will go down. How does that work on the level of the electrons?

As far as I’ve understood, a high voltage will lead to a higher electron drift velocity. So, a higher voltage will always lead to a higher current, as long as the resistance stays constant. When the electrons in the secondary transformer circuit are exposed to the higher voltage, isn’t it inevitable for them to become a stronger current?

I’m aware of the mathematical relationships between the circuits. But I just can't get a grasp on what's really happening there.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I’ve understood, a high voltage will lead to a higher electron drift velocity. So, a higher voltage will always lead to a higher current, as long as the resistance stays constant.

That is only true for a resistor. Not all materials and not all devices behave that way. In particular, in an ideal transformer the resistance is negligible. The voltage and current relationship in an inductor is about the magnetic fields, not about Ohm’s law.

> How does that work on the level of the electrons?

The reason that you are struggling here is that there is nothing at the level of the electrons to be understood. In resistance the individual electrons interact with the lattice in a way crudely described by Drude’s model and more accurately described by quantum mechanics. But there is nothing similar for ideal inductors.

It isn’t that there are not electrons, but there is no interaction between them and the lattice. They simply move as required by the magnetic fields, so if you do understand the field description, then you already understand all there is here. There is no deeper “electron level” to be understood for an ideal inductor.

Answer (score 2):

We can reverse the question to make it less paradoxical

If we place a voltage source $U$ on a resistor $R$, the current that will flow will be $I=U/R$.

If you place this resistor at the secondary of a transformer of ratio $m$, the current will be $m$ times higher : $I=mU/R$

It is the current at the primary that will adapt and become $m^2 U/R$ because the impedance seen from the primary is $R/m^2$.

What happens is that the current flowing at the secondary will induce an emf at the primary: the field seen by the electrons of the primary is not the same as if the secondary did not deliver any current.